# How to update fields in a Quip document from a live app

Tags: quip, liveapps

I was hoping to call an external service from a live App and then update certain named fields within the Quip document with the data returned.

According to the blog: https://quip.com/blog/quip-engineering-live-apps-platform-pt2, it states "Apps cannot access document contents by default".

I really have two questions:

1. How do I name certain fields in a Quip document?
2. How do I write to these fields from a live app which is included in the Quip document?

Thanks very much.

Answer (score 1):

There are no names to fields in Quip documents. Each section has an ID that is retrievable from the API (https://corp.quip.com/dev/automation/documentation#get-thread). The way to edit the contents of a document from a Live App is to call the API (example: https://github.com/quip/quip-apps/tree/master/examples/quip-automation-api-oauth2) and use the edit-document endpoint.